# ruby block/procs and method call

Tags: ruby, methods, block, proc

I'm trying to understand the need of the block `{ |s| puts s }`  here:

```
  def accepts_hash( var )
    print "got: ", var.inspect # will print out what it received
  end

accepts_hash( { :arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN' } )  { |s| puts s }
```

When I run this code, either with or without `{ |s| puts s }` ,

the output is still the same `({ :arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN' })`.

Can anyone please explain what does the block `{ |s| puts s }` do here?

(source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block following your method call `{ |s| puts s }` does nothing until you tell it to. If you continue reading the page they explain blocks further down - here is an example:

```
def accepts_hash( var )
  print "got: ", var.inspect    # will print out what it received
  yield ' jenny from the block' # pass value back to block
end

accepts_hash( { :arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN' } )  { |s| puts s }

=> {:arg1=>"giving arg1", :argN=>"giving argN"} jenny from the block
```

By yielding, we can return and process the block - in this case `s` represents the string we are yielding, and `' jenny from the block'` is its value.

Blocks make ruby more flexible and declarative, allowing you to write idiomatic and human readable code. For example:

```
3.times { p 'hello' } 
=> "hello"
=> "hello"
=> "hello"
```

ruby is a gorgeous lanuage - more info on blocks and practical usage: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/declarative-thinking-with-higher-order-functions-and-blocks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the example that you refer to just illustrates how to pass a block to `accepts_hash`. The method is not implemented to do anything with the block and hence ignores it.

If instead you had a definition like this:

```
def accepts_hash (var, &block)
...
  block.call
end
```

Then it expects an explicit block argument and evaluates it. This should give a different output.

Note that all ruby methods accept blocks implicitly, which is why you are able to pass a block, even when the method signature does not demand it.

You could change the implementation to check if a block is given and evaluate it.

Example:

```
def accepts_hash(var)
  ...
  yield if block_given?
end
```

The yield keyword evaluates the block passed in implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

When you defined `accepts_hash` you didn't tell it to accept a block parameter.  So your block is currently ignored.  To pass in a block you need to use the `&` symbol before a variable name as a parameter.

```
def accepts_hash( var, &blck )
  print "got: ", var.inspect # will print out what it received
  puts
  print "block: ", blck[] # will print out what it received
end

accepts_hash( { :arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN' } )  { 123 } 
 # got: {:arg1=>"giving arg1", :argN=>"giving argN"}
 # block: 123 => nil
```

Alternatively you might use yield to access a block.

```
def accepts_hash( var )
  print "got: ", var.inspect # will print out what it received
  puts
  print "block: ", yield # will print out what it received
end

accepts_hash( { :arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN' } )  { 123 } 
 # got: {:arg1=>"giving arg1", :argN=>"giving argN"}
 # block: 123 => nil
```

Same results, different way of passing a block.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear your doubt, In your code you are passing `Hash` as argument to the method.

```
def accepts_hash( var )
    print "got: ", var.inspect # will print out what it received
end

accepts_hash( { :arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN' } )
```

`{ |s| puts s }` this will not consider as argument in `var`.

`{ |s| puts s }` is generally used to fetch all keys and value of hash.

**For E.g**

```
ab = {:arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN'}

ab.each { |s| puts s }
#Output: 
argN # 1st key
giving argN  # 1st key's value
arg1 # 2nd key
giving arg1 # 2nd key's value
```

If you required to fetch only `keys` and `values` then it is also possible. Like:

```
ab.each { |key, value| puts key } 
=> argN
   arg1
```

In your Method if you just wants to access `keys` of passed Hash as argument then,

```
def accepts_hash( var )
        puts "Keys:=> ", var.keys # will take all keys of Hash
        puts "Values:=>", var.values # will take all values of Hash
end

accepts_hash( { :arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN' } )
```

---

As [@lfender6445](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292069/ruby-block-procs-and-method-call/26292911#answer-26293072) described about `yielding` you can see the effect of `{ |s| puts s }` block by some modification using `split` method where it applied..

**for e.g**

```
def accepts_hash( var )
  print "got: ", var.inspect   # inspect will print the whole object the way it gets
  yield ' pass value back to block'
end

accepts_hash( { :arg1 => 'giving arg1', :argN => 'giving argN' } )  { |s| puts s.split }
Output => got: {:argN=>"giving argN", :arg1=>"giving arg1"}pass
value
back
to
block
```

I hope this may clear you.. Still if you have any doubt then feel free to ask.